# border to the div through the Header

Tags: html, css, border

i want to achieve the border and header like this -

[![][1]][1]

Does css have anything for it?

What i tried and works is-

```
.header{
margin-top:-10px;
background:#fff;
}
```

Are there any other options to achieve this.?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHCVG.jpg

Comment: have you tried using `<fieldset>`? like this http://jsfiddle.net/uP68h/

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_fieldset refer this.

Comment: Forgot abt that.
thank You.

Comment: Fieldset is probably the easiest way to do it (purists may object about semantics).  Other methods are possible but may involve more markup.

Comment: If you want to work with a slightly more general markup than `fieldset/label`, you can get this to work also with help of **pseudo elements** displayed as `table-cell` on the header ... with some additional positioning/margin adjustments it will give you something very similar to `fieldset/label` ... that can be used with more **exciting backgrounds** than what you get in your example where you cover the border with another white layer. Here I threw together a simple [**jsfiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zQpVB/) using some very reusable html5 markup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `:before` or `:after`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gkSYq/)

HTML:

```
<header></header>
```

CSS:

```
header{
  border:3px solid;
  height:300px;
  position:relative;
}

header:before{
  content:'Header';
  position:absolute;
  top:-10px;
  left:50px;
  background:#fff;
  padding:0 20px;
}
```

You can also use two elements:

`header` and `h1`

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gkSYq/1/)

html:

```
<header><h1>Header</h1></header>
```

CSS:

```
header{
  border:3px solid;
  height:300px;
  position:relative;
}

header > h1{
  position:absolute;
  top:-35px;
  left:50px;
  background:#fff;
  padding:0 20px;
}
```

Or keep it really simple and use `fieldset`.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qn8wx/)

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Header</legend>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: In some cases, the text may be significant content (key word) and generated content is not part of the regular document flow. However, for non-critical labels, this is ideal.

Comment: Updated for the possibility of it being a key word @MarcAudet

Answer (score 3):

As already commented, you could use fieldset. Which will work, but isn't the cleanest solution if it isn't used for a form.

> The HTML `<fieldset>` element is used to group several controls as well as labels (`<label>`) within a *web form*.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset).

As alternativ you could try this code:

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    <h3>title</h3>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box 
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.box > h3 {
    position: absolute;
    background: white;
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: -12px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/sM78H/)

Comment: Is there any way to make it automatically adjust to different headings without adding additional CSS for each one?